# Usually trivial Excursion-type process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

How Can i construct a stochastic process $X_t$ which has the property that:

- $X_t \in [0,1]$ for all $t \in [0,T]$ and
- $m(\{t \in [0,T] : X_t>0 \})\leq \delta$, for some pre-chosen $\delta \in [0,T]$?

I was thinking of combining Brownian excursions with some stopping times but I'm not sure how to accomplish this..

Comment: Try conditioning a brownian motion $W_t$ on the event that $W_t$ takes values in $[0,1]$ and on the event that $m({t \in [0,T] : X_t>0})\leq \delta$.

Comment: How can i get an expression for this in closed form though...